# Difference between AnisotropicClamp and AnisotropicWrap in XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, xna

I understand that both are methods of texture filtering but what is the difference between clamp and wrap? Which one is better?

EDIT: I tried both with integrated graphics card and found that AnisotropicWrap showed a lower FPS than AnisotropicClamp. Is it true that AnisotropicWrap renders a better texture than AnisotropicClamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sampler states are responsible for telling the graphics device how to translate texture coordinates into texels.  Say you have a quadrilateral polygon with the UV coordinates arranged like this:

```
(0, 0)     (1, 0) 
  o----------o
  |          |
  o----------o
(0, 1)     (1, 1)
```

Texture coordinates have the range [0, 1].  When this is rendered, the top-left corner of the texture will appear at the top-left corner of the polygon, the bottom-right corner of the texture will appear at the bottom-right corner of the polygon, and so on.

Now say you arrange your UV coordinates like this:

```
(-1, -1)    (2, -1) 
  o----------o
  |          |
  o----------o
(-1, 2)     (2, 2)
```

What happens?  There's no correct way to map these coordinates to the texture, because they're outside of our [0, 1] range!

The answer is that you have to *tell* the device what the correct way is, by specifying either `WRAP` or `CLAMP` sampler states.

A `CLAMP` state clamps the texture coordinates to the [0, 1] range; pixels with coordinates outside of this range will display the closest valid texel.

A `WRAP` state, on the other hand, assumes that the texture coordinates are cyclical.  A coordinate of 1.5 will be treated as 0.5, a coordinate of -0.25 will be treated as 0.75, and so on.  This causes the texture to *wrap*, giving it a tiled appearance.

Comment: The OP also asked which mode is "better", and while I am not the OP, I feel like that particular part of the question wasn't really addressed (while you did an excellent job answering the rest of the question!). In what scenarios would I want to use one sampling state over the other? While I can use the `WRAP` state and expect the texture to be tiled in appearance, what can I expect the texture to look like if I use the `CLAMP` state?

Comment: You can't really say that one is "better" than the other.  With the CLAMP state the texture will appear "stretched" around the edges if you specify texture coordinates that exceed the [0, 1] range.  So long as you keep your coordinates within that range, they'll look identical.  Specifying CLAMP is required in certain scenarios, for example with non-power-of-two textures under the Reach profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an XNA developer but they looks different for me.

[SamplerState.AnisotropicClamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate.anisotropicclamp%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx)

> Contains default state for anisotropic filtering and texture
>   coordinate clamping.

[SamplerState.AnisotropicWrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate.anisotropicwrap%28v=xnagamestudio.35%29.aspx)

> Contains default state for anisotropic filtering and texture
>   coordinate wrapping.

Check these links also;

- http://iloveshaders.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-state-objects-in-xna.html
- https://code.google.com/p/slimdx/